# Geometry Nodes - how i add a simple switch

Tags: geometry-nodes

I like to have a simple switch e.g.: "is it 1 then take this branch, is it 0 then take the other branch."

but i cant get it right to work :-/ the only thing that i found ist the Switch node, but with this i only can geht a different input and take another output. Can anybody helb me out?!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just change the type to geometry and you can use it like this:

[image]

Comment: Ahh... i thought the "other branch" would be calculatet then for no reason. But if the other branch does not have an ouput - blender is smart enough to not calculatet them. Thanks for your answer! :-D

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @DraconiX the other branch is not calculated, because the tree is evaluted from right to left ([my answer] explaining it thoroughly), and switch directs the evaluation either up or down.